# Is it effective to have my opponent arrested?

Tags: tropico-4

Some pesky citizens have started talking about elections, and many of them have already declared their intent to vote for a specific citizen rather than me.  Luckily, my prison still has some space available...

Since the elections haven't started yet, would it be beneficial to have the citizen that is planning to run against me arrested?  Can he still run while in jail?  If not, will whoever replaces him have the same support, or will it potentially decrease due to the imprisonment and potentially having a candidate that is not as good of a match for the opposition's ideals?

Comment: Remind me never to run against you if you ever run for office.

Comment: Can imprisoned citizens vote? IF not, perhaps you could just arrest everyone who supports the opposition instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, it's the opposite of what you're thinking. If you arrest an opponent either before or in the elections, someone else would take his place with increased support, and the same ideals. As well, everyone who watched the arrest, and his/hers family will have decreased respect for you, meaning it will be more likely for them to vote against you. So it's not really beneficial to arrest anyone who's willing to go against you in the elections.

Comment: this is so unrealistic :P

Comment: well all you have to do is to arrest his replacement too!

Comment: @yx_ Welcome to a never ending loop, or at least until you run out of citizens.

Comment: @mordi2k that's perfect though! IF there are no citizens, then no one can vote against you!

Comment: Out of curiosity, does this also apply when you arrange for an "accident"?